# how to check for multiple conditions including null value in when statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to check for two conditions-  when ( a field is not null & equal to a value) then do something, but i'm getting type miss match error. can you please help?

```
join_df6.withColumn(
    'NI', 
     when(
        join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr.isNotNull() & join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr == '00000',
        join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr
     ).when(
        join_df6.s4cordislips_posnr.isNotNull(),
        join_df6.s4cordislips_posnr
      ).otherwise(join_df6.s4ibdlips_posnr)
)
```

**Error**

> u"cannot resolve '((`s4chvw_zzbatposnr` IS NOT NULL) AND `s4chvw_zzbatposnr`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((`s4chvw_zzbatposnr` IS NOT NULL) AND `s4chvw_zzbatposnr`)' (boolean and string).;

Answer (score 1):

The conditions inside the `when` are evaluated according to [python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), and the bitwise and (`&`) has higher precedence than all comparison operators including `==` (HT to [@cronoik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514015/how-to-check-for-multiple-conditions-including-null-value-in-when-statement/57514241?noredirect=1#comment101498290_57514241) for pointing this out).

```
join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr.isNotNull() & join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr == '00000'
```

Is being evaluated as:

```
(join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr.isNotNull() & join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr) == '00000'
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# this & is evaluated first
```

Which causes your data type mismatch error because `.isNotNull()` returns a boolean and `join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr` seems to be a string.

The solution is to always use parentheses for multiple conditions. In your case, you should do:

```
join_df6.withColumn(
    'NI', 
     when(
        join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr.isNotNull() & (join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr == '00000'),
        join_df6.s4chvw_zzbatposnr
     ).when(
        join_df6.s4cordislips_posnr.isNotNull(),
        join_df6.s4cordislips_posnr
      ).otherwise(join_df6.s4ibdlips_posnr)
)
```

---

Comment: I can't test it currently, but I think it is not left to right. It is normal python [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and the logical and `&` has a higher priority as the comparison `==` operator.

Comment: @cronoik you are probably right, that makes more sense. I will update.